# Scanner: Getting rid of "Resource leak: '<unassigned Closeable value>' is never closed"

Tags: java, spring, exception, java.util.scanner, try-with-resources

I am trying to make a kind of utility method to read text files from resources in Spring Boot. In order to read the files i am facing them as `InputStream`s:

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(fileLocationInClasspath);
InputStream resourceInputStream = resource.getInputStream();
```

(Note that`Resource#getInputStream` **throws IOException**)

Then I am trying to use a *Scanner* as mentioned in [stupid scanner tricks](https://community.oracle.com/blogs/pat/2004/10/23/stupid-scanner-tricks) instead of a `Reader` or something, since it is an elegant-simple way to do so.

However, i am having trouble getting rid of the warning mentioned in question's title. Even if i simply call `scanner.close()` (before java-8 way), the warning will remain.

**Try #1 (first attemt):**

```
public static String readFileFromResources(String fileName) throws IOException {
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new ClassPathResource(fileName).getInputStream()).useDelimiter("\\A")) {
        return sc.next();
    }
}
```

**Try #2:**

```
public static String readFileFromResources(String fileName) throws IOException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new ClassPathResource(fileName).getInputStream()).useDelimiter("\\A");
    String text = sc.next();
    sc.close();
    return text;
}
```

**Try #3 (Warning goes away):**

```
public static String readFileFromResources(String fileName) throws IOException {
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new ClassPathResource(fileName).getInputStream()).useDelimiter("\\A")) {
        return sc.next();
    } catch (Exception e) // Note Exception class
    {
        throw new IOException(e); //Need to catch this later
    }
}
```

Could someone explain why **try#1** and **try#2** throws a warning? I guess **try #3** does not, because we catch all the possible exceptions. But the only exception that can be thrown there is the `IOException` from `getInputStream()` method. If `Scanner` is suspicious for any exception, why does not it force us to catch this exception? After all, catching exceptions using `Exception`, is not recommended.

Finally, i thought, maybe this is an STS (Spring tool suite) problem?

(If it plays any role-> JDK Version: 1.8.0_191)

Comment: Be advised, the article to which you refer is written in 2004, that's a long time ago. Things mentioned in the article *might* be outdated.

Comment: @MCEmperor Yea, i noticed that and i completely understand what you mean. If this would be the problem,  shouldn't `Scanner#useDelimeter` be deprecated then? or something in Documentation at least?

Comment: It's not a problem with `useDelimiter`. My comment was merely a general warning about the age of the article.

Comment: @MCEmperor   Are you sure? https://i.imgur.com/gZQyDpl.png

Comment: Well, I should have said "It *should* not be a problem with `useDelimiter`. But I couldn't reproduce it, since I'm not using Eclipse. I suspect, however, that calling `useLocale` instead of `useDelimiter` emits a warning in the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is actually with `useDelimiter()` as the following code has no such issue and should yield the same result:

```
public static String readFileFromResources(String fileName) throws IOException {
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new ClassPathResource(fileName).getInputStream())) {
        sc.useDelimiter("\\A");
        return sc.next();
    }
}
```

I am not sure what exactly causes the resource leak, but I believe its the command chaining you used

Comment: Eh...This is a thing i did not try. Yeah, this will make it disappear. Thanks.